# Java: LockSupport.parkNanos vs Thread.sleep(...)

Tags: java, multithreading

In some cases, most of us write things like this:

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(2000); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   ; // do nothing
}
```

Whether right or wrong, acceptable only in some test harnesses, is not my point.
My point is that the same code could be written,more succinctly, as:

```
  LockSupport.parkNanos(2000* 1000000);
```

is there any reason why I should favour one approach over the other.

Comment: My initial thought is that I find grokking 2000ms a lot easier than 2000 * 1000000 ns!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The docs for the method `parkNanos` provides the conditions in which the method can return. One of those conditions is: *the call spuriously (that is, for no reason) returns*. So basically it's OK to use it if you don't mind spurious wake-ups and some other Thread "unparking" the waiting thread in consideration. And of course, the comment by Jon pretty much nails the reasoning for preferring one over another.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but it can still help developers looking for more insight on LockSupport.

For completion, here is a good article showing what those spurious returns could looks like: https://hazelcast.com/blog/locksupport-parknanos-under-the-hood-and-the-curious-case-of-parking/
TLDR: the call may return after few μs depending on the JVM (HotSpot, Dalvik, IBM) and even the host.

Answer (score 22):

Readability: `Thread.sleep` has a pretty intuitive meaning. How would you *describe* (to another developer) your use of `LockSupport.parkNanos`? If that description primarily consists of "I want the current **thread** to **sleep**" then surely `Thread.sleep` is more descriptive.

The conciseness comes from the lack of interrupt handling - so create a wrapper method to do this if you want, which propagates the exception as a `RuntimeException`. Heck, if you're creating a wrapper method, you can use either implementation, although another thread could of course *unpark* your "sleeping" thread in the same way as it could interrupt it...

Comment: Isn't the main difference that during `sleep` processor can switch context to another thread, and during `park` only waits some time (almost like loop with nul operations)?  (without context switching - massive overhead)

Comment: @razor: No, I don't *think* that's the case - at least, the documentation doesn't explicitly state that it's a spin lock.

Answer (score 1):

[LockSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) has a much more limited application, and does not support Exception handling. If you have to only lock a single thread, it is OK.

From the API:

> these methods are designed to be used as tools for creating
>   higher-level synchronization utilities, and are not in themselves
>   useful for most concurrency control applications.

Comment: Most of the time the exception handling is pretty much useless. The coder can guarantee that the thread will not be interrupted... hence my question